# Vue test utils incorrect value of computed

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-test-utils

Hello I have checked the behaviour in application and it works with same data from `api` as I'm providing in mocked api call `Api.contracts.getContractDetails.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ data }));` However, the value of `hasWatermark` computed is `false` - while it should be true.

How can I debug this? Is it possible to check computed in tests? This is my test:

```js
function createWrapper() {
    const i18n = new VueI18n({
      locale: "en",
      missing: jest.fn(),
    });

    return mount(EmployeeContract, {
      i18n,
      localVue,
      store,
      mocks: { $route: { query: {}, params: { id: "123" } }, $buefy: { toast: { open: jest.fn() } } },
      stubs: ["spinner", "router-link", "b-switch"],
    });

it("should add watermark for preview once it has rejected status", async () => {
    const data = singleContract;
    Api.contracts.getContractDetails.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ data }));
    const wrapper = createWrapper();

    await flushPromises();
    expect(wrapper.vm.hasWatermark).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: You can debug tests locally in VS Code. It's not the best experience (yet) but at least you can set break points and see values https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting

Comment: There's not enough context here to determine the problem. How is `hasWatermark` related to the mock you've created? What is `singleContract`?

Comment: @tony19 its a giant object with mocked value from API call. The thing it is working as expected in browser, only tests fail.